# Ethereum usability in IoT

Tags: transactions, iot

Curently minimal transaction cost is around 0.1$. And it's VERY high for most of IoT applications, where service price is less than 0,1$.

Is there any solutions, works, startups anything about it?

Comment: A minimum transaction would be 21,000 gas, and looking at http://ethgasstation.info/minerTable.php currently you could get down to 0.5 Gwei gas price and still have your transaction confirmed relatively quickly. That's 10,500 Gwei or 0.0000105 ether. With ether at ~$300 each, that's $0.00315 transaction cost (less than a third of a penny). If you're paying $0.10 per transaction, you either have a gas-guzzling function, or are paying too much for gas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want payment channels or state channels in general (payment channel is a type of state channel).

**Payment channels**

A [payment channel](https://medium.com/@jgm.orinoco/introduction-to-ethereum-payment-channels-a16fbe1a7181) works like in roughly three phases (see [this post](https://blog.gridplus.io/a-simple-ethereum-payment-channel-implementation-2d320d1fad93) for more details/context):

1. Open a new channel with a sender and a recipient

   ```
   function OpenChannel(address token, address to, uint amount) {
     if (amount == 0) { throw; }
     if (to == msg.sender) { throw; }
     if (active_ids[msg.sender][to] != bytes32(0)) { throw; }

     bytes32 id = sha3(msg.sender, to, now);

     Channel memory _channel;
     _channel.deposit = amount;
     _channel.sender = msg.sender;
     _channel.recipient = to;
     _channel.token = token;

     ERC20 t = ERC20(token);
     if (!t.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount)) { throw; }

     channels[id] = _channel;

     active_ids[msg.sender][to] = id;
   }
   ```
2. Sign messages from sender to recipient. These messages contain a `value`, which can be verifiably sent to the recipient at any time.

   ```
   var sha3 = require('solidity-sha3').default;

   var _value = 0.01*Math.pow(10, 18)    
   var value = _value.toString(16)    
   let _msg_hash = sha3(`0x${channel_id}`, _value);    
   let msg_hash = Buffer.from(_msg_hash.substr(2, 64), 'hex');     
   let sig = util.ecsign(msg_hash, keys.test.privateKey);    
   let parsed_sig = {      
     v: sig.v.toString(16),      
     r: sig.r.toString('hex'),      
     s: sig.s.toString('hex')    
   };    
   latest_value = value;    
   latest_sig = parsed_sig;    
   latest_msg_hash = msg_hash.toString('hex')
   ```
3. Close the channel. This is a transaction that takes one of the above signed messages and plays it on chain. This will transfer that messages funds to the recipient and delete the channel.

   ```
   function CloseChannel(bytes32[4] h, uint8 v, uint256 value) {
     // h[0]    Channel id
     // h[1]    Hash of (id, value)
     // h[2]    r of signature
     // h[3]    s of signature

     // Grab the channel in question
     if (channels[h[0]].deposit == 0) { throw; }
     Channel memory _channel;
     _channel = channels[h[0]];

     if (msg.sender != _channel.sender && msg.sender != _channel.recipient) { throw; }

     address signer = ecrecover(h[1], v, h[2], h[3]);
     if (signer != _channel.sender) { throw; }

     // Make sure the hash provided is of the channel id and the amount sent
     bytes32 proof = sha3(h[0], value);
     // Ensure the proof matches, send the value, send the remainder, and delete the channel
     if (proof != h[1]) { throw; }
     else if (value > _channel.deposit) { throw; }

     // Pay recipient and refund sender the remainder
     ERC20 t = ERC20(_channel.token);
     if (!t.transfer(_channel.recipient, value)) { throw; }
     else if (!t.transfer(_channel.sender, _channel.deposit-value)) { throw; }

     // Close the channel
     delete channels[h[0]];
     delete active_ids[_channel.sender][_channel.recipient];

   }
   ```

**Gas Considerations**

Note that a single token transfer costs 50,000 gas. As you have pointed out, this is cost prohibitive for a microtransaction context (although the exact dollar amount depends on the `gasPrice` used). A payment channel costs roughly 250,000 gas to open and 250,000 gas to close, depending on the implementation.

This means that a payment channel's overhead is roughly 10 transactions, but if you expect 10,000 micropayments per deposit, that's a cost savings of 1000x.